# Google Map using asp.net in 3 tier

Tags: asp.net

I have query regarding Google Map.
I want to take multiple locations from user & store it in database.after that google map must be displayed with those multiple locations

I want code in basic asp.net with 3 tier architecture

Comment: What have you tried?  Please only ask specific problems.  We are not a code writing or resource recommending service.

Comment: how to get multiple location in map from database. i have tried using repeater in javascript